# Possible to repair pressed wood?

Tags: repair

The legs of a pressed wood cabinet have swollen in size and are shredding.
Are there successful methods and/or products for reinforcing them?

Comment: I would look to replace them.

Comment: Yes. Once pressed wood starts to deteriorate, there is not "fix" for it.